# Which quantities and formulas are counterparts to each other for electrical and magnetic quantities?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, circuits

Changed from original question: Which quantities and formulas do you think are counterparts to each other for electrical and magnetic quantities?

If any of you are familiar with physics where some sources make a deep comparison between translational and rotational quantities in order for students to be able to see that the rotational takes some form based off the translational quantities, I want to be able to achieve something like that for electric and magnetic quantities. Like for example, magnetic field and electric field quantities.

I would really want formulas or a source that actually does what I am saying, but having regular concepts like electric field and magnetic field be explained side to side even though they do not have a formula would be fine. I think they do though, I did not check yet.

My point is I at least want a basis on which quantities are counterparts to each other so I can do further research. Like for example resistance can be a counterpart to reluctance. I want clear answers. I am aware not every quantity can be put in a table and I would expect it to have a counterpart. I am fine with also people saying that this quantity is like that.

Edit: No, I don't want to relate it to motion. That was just an example.
Another example I could point out is comparing formulas between differential and integral calculus. I just really want an analogy between concepts.

Comment: what question do you have about electronics? ... questions about people's thoughts do not count ... there is a difference between `which is a counterpart?` and `which do you think is a counterpart?`

Comment: I recommend you check out @WBeaty 's resources on http://amasci.com/ele-edu.html -- not exactly an answer, but a good electronics learning resource.

Comment: Sorry if the wordings confused you. But like I have mentioned about translational and rotational motion, I am looking for counterparts which objectively can work. I am aware that it just might not that be clear cut when it comes to comparing electrical and magnetic quantities, but that is why I am asking. The wording was just me not being cautious about sentence construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic and direct comparison between electrical and magnetic quantities can be done using magnetic equivalent circuits.

The magnetic field of a structure can be approximately assumed to be homogeneous at least locally.
[image: Element with homogeneous magnetic field]

With the magnetic flux density (similar to electric *current density*):
$$B_k = \mu_0\mu_rH_k$$

the magnetic flux through the element (similar to electric *current*):
$$\phi_k = A_kB_k$$

the magnetic voltage (MMF) across the element (similar to *voltage*):
$$\Theta_k = l_kH_k$$

and the magnetic reluctance (similar to *resistance*):
$$R_k = \frac{\Theta_k}{\phi_k}=\frac{l_k}{\mu_0\mu_{rk}A_k}$$

as well as the magnetic conductivity or permeance (similar to electric *conductance*):
$$\Lambda_k = \frac{1}{R_k}=\frac{\mu_0\mu_{rk}A_k}{l_k}$$

For calculations using magnetic circuits you can use familiar rules from electrical circuits.

The magnetic flux at a joint of elements is similar to *KCL*:
$$\sum_k \phi_k = 0$$

Something similar to *KVL* can also be applied:
$$\sum_k\Theta_k = Ni$$

where an additional MMF is introduced by a coil with *N* windings and the current *i*.

With this you can construct magnetic equivalent circuits that are very similar to electric circuits:
[image: Magnetic equivalent circuit of a magnetic actuator]

For more information and a table about the analogy of magnetic and electric circuits (with slightly different notation) you can check out the [wikipedia on magnetic circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit#Summary_of_analogy). Also most textbooks on electric motors/machines cover magnetic circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Translational is in the same direction such as linear motion , tangential motion , resistor voltage and current.

Rotational is the sinusoidal variation of something such as the centripetal acceleration vector change with speed, frequency or RPM such as the oscillation between LC or equivalent 2nd order reactive components in a circuit where the current can be something out of phase with the voltage.

Vector sum of power is the X axis real or resistive power in Watts and the orthogonal reactive power or VAR.

EMI can be seen as the coupling of E-fields into high impedance voltage or H-fields into low impedance currents.   The ratio of E/H fields could be vector field in Ohms/m which for stray EMI is a relatively high impedance that couples at higher frequencies where wire inductance and load resistance and capacitance result in some attenuation or injection of crosstalk from this vector impedance ratio.

The coupling between source of interference and the target are often described as mutual coupling of stray magnetic AC current into a transmission line or wire loop inductance with some mutual coupling of impedance ratios.  Nearby current surges producing glitches by means of the RF rotational coupling of H fields into rotational currents with a load resistance that results in linear translation to voltage. The waveforms are often a transient with ringing or an exponential decay of rotational resonance.  The 90% rise or fall time becomes equivalent to 35% of the period for the equivalent fundamental frequency.

High voltage transients created by collapsing a magnetic field current create a  high E-field in [V/m] that can couple into  high impedances by a crosstalk of some [pF] This rise/fall time again can be converted to an equivalent rotational frequency and this capacitive impedance which forms an impedance divider to the unintentional received signal as a translation glitch.

Similar to a recent answer comparing capacitor currents to a shock absorber , the spring mass being the inductor, as the vehicle moves rotationally over a pothole,  the coupling to the body or frame depends on the capacitive coupling force of the axel to the mass of the vehicle while the wheels translate the road surface to a rotational load.  The gyroscopic rotational  forces of the wheels are barely felt compare to the translation of the fast moving car when power steering is used.

I doubt any of this helps any student understand the correlation of physical to electrical motions in linear and reactive currents for translational and rotational motion, but I had fun writing it.

Comment: The translational and rotational motion was just an example. Like how velocity has an angular velocity, I wanted electrical quantities to be compared to magnetic quantities that might possibly be their counterparts. But this is the correct answer if someone wanted the topic about motion types being related to electric circuits. Though I don't mean to undermine the answer, even I learned something from some of the comparisons you made. It's just that it wasn't what I was asking for.

Comment: Magnetic Permeability mu, is analogous to Electric insulator Permittivity or the Dielectric Constant Dk and the energy stored 1/LI^2 in the internal H field may be compared to the energy stored in a dielectric cap E=1/2LI^2 and both oscillate 180 deg out of phase in voltage when in series sharing the same current or 180 deg out of phase in current when sharing the same voltage in parallel.  Yet for impedance  a negative impedance inverter for cap. becomes an active inductor and is used in RC active filters to emulate LC filters of any order or Q shape factor.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(electricity_and_magnetism).

> The electric field (E) is the dual of the magnetic field (H).
> The electric displacement field (D) is the dual of the magnetic flux density (B).
> Faraday's law of induction is the dual of Ampère's circuital law.
> Gauss's law for electric field is the dual of Gauss's law for magnetism.
> The electric potential is the dual of the magnetic potential.
> Permittivity is the dual of permeability.
> Electrostriction is the dual of magnetostriction.
> Piezoelectricity is the dual of piezomagnetism.
> Ferroelectricity is the dual of ferromagnetism.
> An electrostatic motor is the dual of a magnetic motor;
> Electrets are the dual of permanent magnets;
> The Faraday effect is the dual of the Kerr effect;
> The Aharonov–Casher effect is the dual to the Aharonov–Bohm effect;
> The hypothetical magnetic monopole is the dual of electric charge.